# Is there a way of combining HTML tags like you can with style tabs?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript of combining HTML tags like you can with style tags?

Example HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
  <p>I am paragraph one.</p>
  <p>I am paragraph two.</p>
  <p>I am paragraph three.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

something like:
document.body.getElementsByTagNames("div p")

I made up getElementsByTagNames.

div p {color: green}

You can find all  tags in a document with code like the following:

```
var divisions = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

And you can find all

tags within the first  tag with code like this:

```
var paragraphs = divisions[0].getElementsByTagname("p");
```

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596101996/re285.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div p').forEach(p => {
  console.log(p.outerHTML);
  p.style.color = 'green';
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>I am paragraph one.</p>
  <p>I am paragraph two.</p>
  <p>I am paragraph three.</p>
</div>
```